# How to add an entry to the history of a work item using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add an entry to the History section of a work item. By history I mean the actual change history and not the comments section(System.History is the field for this section). Is there a REST API that will let me do this?

[Work Item history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ixIx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The History section records every change made to the work item. You can use [update work item rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update the workitem. Then the update will be recorded in the History thread.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

See below example to add a tag to the workitem. The action will be recorded in History section.

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/wit/workitems/40?api-version=6.0-preview.3"
$connectionToken='Personal access token'
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$b= @"
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Tags",
    "value": "Tag1; Tag2"
  }
]
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $murl -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method patch  -Body $b -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"
```

You will see the entry is added to History thread:

[image]

Comment: I was trying to add an entry without making any changes to the standard work item fields. I have a custom extension control within the work item and any changes to that are not captured in the history.

Comment: I am afraid there is not a rest api that can add a history entry directly. You might have to use the workaround to update the workitem. For example [add a comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), or create a custom field and update that field when you make changes to your custom extension control. etc.

Comment: Got it. I'm planning to go with either of these options. Thanks for the confirmation!